# Why am I getting NAs and unexpected results when pulling coefficients from a lm model in a for loop?

Tags: r

I'm trying to run a different model for 28 experiment by location (latitude) values in order to determine the unique regression slope for each experiment at each location. [Here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/5henzs8o83rvikj/grain%20yield%20by%20environment%20long.csv?dl=0) is a link to my data. Similar code has worked before for looping regressions when varying the predictor, but now this code is doing several confusing things. The P value and slope columns contain 28 rows of NAs followed by 55 rows of values, and the R squared column contains 88 rows of values. I ran a sample model and couldn't find any of the values anywhere in the table.

```
data$Grain<- as.numeric(as.character(data$Grain))
data2 <- subset(data, Age >1)

ls1 <- list()
ls2 <- list()
ls3 <- list()
data2$Key3 <- paste(data2$LAT, data2$Experiment)

for (i in unique(data2$Key3)){ 
  model <- lm(as.formula(paste0("Grain", "~", "Age")), subset(data2, Key3 == i))
  pval <- summary(model)$coefficients[,4] #extracts P values for model
  rsq <- summary(model)$r.squared
  slope <- summary(model)$coefficients[,1]
  ls1 <- c(ls1, pval[2]) #extracts P values of second row, which is the predictor Age
  ls2 <- c(ls2, rsq)
  ls3 <- c(ls3, slope[2]) #extracts slope of second row, which is the predictor Age
}

Ps <- do.call(rbind, ls1)
Rs <- do.call(rbind, ls2)
slopes <- do.call(rbind, ls3)

table <- cbind(Ps, Rs, slopes)

## Sample model- sorry the Key3 values are so ugly
summary(lm(Grain~Age, subset(data2, Key3 == '44.06751 IREE- N Rate')))
```

Any ideas on  how to get the actual P, R2, and slopes into a table? Any thoughts as to why this is spitting out so many rows of NAs?

Comment: don't forget that the default sep in `paste()` is a `space`. Check if that is causing the error. ```data2$Key3 <- paste0(data2$LAT, data2$Experiment)```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code seems to work now. Use `Key3 ='44.06751IREE- N Rate'` if you use `paste0()` because it does not add a space by default unlike `paste()`

```
data$Grain <- readr::parse_number(data$Grain)
data2 <- subset(data, Age > 1)

ls1 <- list()
ls2 <- list()
ls3 <- list()
data2$Key3 <- paste0(data2$LAT, data2$Experiment)

for (i in unique(data2$Key3)){ 
  model <- lm(as.formula(paste0("Grain", "~", "Age")), subset(data2, Key3 == i))
  pval <- summary(model)$coefficients[,4] #extracts P values for model
  rsq <- summary(model)$r.squared
  slope <- summary(model)$coefficients[,1]
  ls1 <- c(ls1, pval[2]) #extracts P values of second row, which is the predictor Age
  ls2 <- c(ls2, rsq)
  ls3 <- c(ls3, slope[2]) #extracts slope of second row, which is the predictor Age
}

Ps <- do.call(rbind, ls1)
Rs <- do.call(rbind, ls2)
slopes <- do.call(rbind, ls3)

table <- cbind(Ps, Rs, slopes)

## Sample model- sorry the Key3 values are so ugly
summary(lm(Grain~Age, subset(data2, Key3 == '44.06751IREE- N Rate')))

summary(lm(Grain~Age, subset(data2, Key3 == '44.06751IREE- N Rate')))

Call:
lm(formula = Grain ~ Age, data = subset(data2, Key3 == "44.06751IREE- N Rate"))

Residuals:
   Min     1Q Median     3Q    Max 
  -245   -210     19    135    586 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)   1175.3       68.1    17.2   <2e-16 ***
Age           -310.2       22.2   -14.0   <2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 211 on 132 degrees of freedom
  (10 observations deleted due to missingness)
Multiple R-squared:  0.596, Adjusted R-squared:  0.593 
F-statistic:  195 on 1 and 132 DF,  p-value: <2e-16
```